# 3 Nested foreach loops

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to migrate some vms - we don't have DRS set up in the cluster, and i need to move it to 3 specific hosts, and 4 specific datastores.

How can i run a nested foreach loop that takes only the 1st option, applies the other 2 loops to this first option, then continues with the loop.

for instance, i have 3 vm's, 2 hosts, 2 datastores.

```
$vms = a,b,c
$hosts = 1,2
$datastores = red, blue
```

The desired effect would be a loop that takes "a", applies "1" as the $host, "red" as the $datastore. Next iteration would take "b", apply "2" as the $host, "blue" as the $datastore. Next iteration would take "c", apply "1" as the $host, "red" as the $datastore....

my code so far:

```
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
for ($h = 0;$h -le 2; $h += 1) {
for ($d = 0;$d -le 2; $d += 1) {
write-output $vm;
write-output $vhosts[$h];
write-output $datastores[$d];
}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `foreach` loop. Initialize the variables `$h` and `$d` to zero outside the loop, and then increment them at the end of the loop, resetting back to zero if they're outside their respective ranges.

If `$hosts` and `$datastores` are always the same length, you don't even need two variables, just use one.

Free ProTip™: An easy way to increment a variable with an upper boundary is using the modulo operator:

```
$h = ($h + 1) % $Hosts.Length
```

Comment: that works as you described. Quick question about the modulo operator, the syntax doesn't make sense to me. how do you create a boundary with a foreach loop? The way i see it, it takes $h current value, and adds one for each $hosts total length?

Comment: @JustinBeagle: It takes the value of `$h`, adds one, divides by `$hosts.Length`, and takes the remainder of that. The remainder is the same as `$h` as long as it's less than `$hosts.Length`, but if it's the same, the remainder is 0. It's just a shorthand trick. If you prefer, you can just use an `if` to reset the variable to 0 when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that should do what you want without having to do any indexing. As mentioned above, you only need one `foreach` loop. This code uses multiple assignment to take the various lists apart, resetting them to the original value when they are empty.

```
$vms = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
$hosts = 1,2
$datastores = "red", "blue", "green"

# Initialize the host and datastore lists
$hl = $dl = $null
foreach ($v in $vms)
{
    # if the host list is empty, reset it
    if (! $hl) { $hl = $hosts } 

    # extract the head and tail of the host list
    $h, $hl = $hl

    # If the data store list is empty, reinitialize it
    if (! $dl) { $dl = $datastores }

    # Extract the head and tail of the datastore list
    $d, $dl = $dl

    # Now do something with all three elements
    "vm $v host $h datastore $d"
}
```

Comment: That's really cool, i don't get the syntax of how `$d, $d1 = $d1` pulls the first object from the array, places it in $d, but that's really cool - thanks!